# org.apache.nutch.searcher in nutch 1.7

Tags: eclipse, apache, nutch

I'm new in nutch. I'm using nutch 1.7 and the crawl is done. 
My problem is how can I retrieve crawl data?
In nutch 1.1 there was a package called org.apache.nutch.searcher that provide this.
But if I import the nutch1.1.jar in my Java Application and try to run the old code

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/JavaDemoApplication (visible at this link)

it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.nutch.indexer.NutchSimilarity overrides final method lengthNorm.(Ljava/lang/String;I)F
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.nutch.searcher.LuceneSearchBean.init(LuceneSearchBean.java:84)
    at org.apache.nutch.searcher.LuceneSearchBean.<init>(LuceneSearchBean.java:51)
    at org.apache.nutch.searcher.NutchBean.<init>(NutchBean.java:103)
    at org.apache.nutch.searcher.NutchBean.<init>(NutchBean.java:78)
    at MyCrawler.main(MyCrawler.java:57)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks
Danilo

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be because of incompatibility of Nutch version1.1 and 1.2 with versions of Lucene higher than 3.1.0. I faced the same problem and resolved it by using the Nutch and SOLR integration instead of Nutch and - Lucene integration directly. You can look at this tutorial:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2012/06/building-a-java-application-with-apache-nutch-and-solr/